# MySQL - selecting a single field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a few fields, and I'm trying to select a single field from it

`sELECT ID FROM table`

and it doesn't work, I get a empty array :(

But if I select 2 fields (or more) it works and I get a array with both `ID` and `content`:

`sELECT ID, content FROM table`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This should work fine.  Can you paste the results of `describe table;` please?

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, I'm new to sql :)

Comment: Seems impossible. are you sure you don't have a empty where somewhere?

Comment: "I get a empty array" The problem is in your code where are you fetching the results. please post the relevant part of your code.

Comment: the ID field has a "auto_increment" note on the "extra" column in phpmyadmin, and others don't. could this be the issue?

Comment: nevermind, found the problem, it was a bad ORDER BY placement :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't seem you're doing anything wrong. To be sure though some tips

- Fix your casing: `ID` versus `anotherfield` is confusing. Also make sure your casing is the same in you query and database
- Use backticks around fieldnames: (hmm, don't know how to show that without it becoming code in stackoverflow, but encase ID in these things: `

If this fails, post your database design and possibly content here, and the results of your query.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  `table`.`ID` FROM `table`
```

and if you want to select the latest record for example, do this...

```
SELECT  `table`.`ID` FROM `table` ORDER BY `table`.`ID` DESC LIMIT 1
```